# Sort Function Treats Headers Inconsistently in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I select an area of my worksheet and then use the "Sort" function in Excel 2010 (in the "Data" tab), sometimes the row *above* my selection is treated as a header row, and sometimes the *top row* of my selection is treated as a header row. There does not appear to be any rhyme or reason for the different behaviour (it seems essentially random). Can anyone tell me how I *can* get consistent behaviour on this? Thanks!

Comment: Open the Sort Dialog box, on the upper right corner there is an option named: My data has headers, make sure you have unchecked the option.

Comment: Lee, the issue is that sometimes the top line of my selection is treated as the header, and sometimes the line above my selection is treated as the header. In both cases, that option is checked.